# a code which can load for the first time in layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

is the following statement correct? (about _Layout.cshtml using razor view engine)
every codes in layout would be divide in to 2 types:
 - static codes like `<div>...</div>` which is load only for the first time and do note Post or PostBack anymore.
 - dynamic codes like `@ViewBag.Title=...` which always must calculate and post and postback to the client.

if your answer is "yes" my second question is :
is there a way to write dynamic code that accept a value for the first time in run time and do not change it and do not need to post it to the client every time that user clicks a new page?

Answer (score 0):

Every Razor page (no matter whether it contains static or dynamic code) is dynamically evaluated at runtime by the Razor view engine and converted to static HTML which is sent to the client. This evaluation happens once the controller action has finished executing and returned some view. So to summarize:

1. An HTTP client request hits the web server
2. The routing engine resolves the controller action which should handle it
3. The action executes and selects a Razor view to be rendered passing it a view model
4. The view engine evaluates the Razor view and converts it to pure static HTML which is sent to the client.

As far as your question about posts and postbacks are concerned I really don't see any relation.

Comment: are you telling me that: all of the layout will be posted fore every calls to the client. i thought that only RenderSections will post and layout remain unchanged in the client side (to reduce data traffic)

Comment: @Rzassar, the entire HTML is sent to the client. There is no such notion as layouts or sections that a browser understands. A browser understands entire HTML pages and this is what is sent every time.